# Submit button submits the wrong form

Tags: form-submit, forms

I have two forms on the same page like this:

```
<section class="login_column box" >

    <h3>For patients:</h3>

    <form id="patients_form" name="patients_form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>" method="POST">

    <fieldset>

        <p><label for="patient_login">Email:</label><input type="text" id="patient_login" name="patient_login" placeholder="Email" value="" required></p>

        <p><label for="patient_password">Password:</label><input type="password" id="patient_password" name="patient_password" placeholder="Password" value="" required></p>

        <p><label></label><button id="patients" style="margin-top:17px;" name="patients" type="submit">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Login&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</button></p>

    </fieldset>

    </form>

</section>


<section class="login_column box">

    <h3>For physicians:</h3>

    <form id="physicians_form" name="physicians_form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>" method="POST">

    <fieldset>

        <p><label for="physician_login">Email:</label><input type="text" id="physician_login" name="physician_login" placeholder="Email" value="" required></p>

        <p><label for="physician_password">Password:</label><input type="password" id="physician_password" name="physician_password" placeholder="Password" value="" required></p>

        <p><label></label><button id="physicians" name="physicians" style="margin-top:17px;" value="Login" type="submit">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Вход&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</button></p>

    </fieldset>

    </form>

</section>
```

When some of the submit buttons is pressed the first form is submitted even though that the second submit button may be pressed. How to ensure that each submit button submits only its own form?

Comment: Do you have a live URL? or a Demo we can take a look at? That would probably help a lot.

Comment: Yes, I have, but it's in Cyrillic. Hope it won't be a problem.
http://scanner.strangerstudio.net/index.php?page=%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8+%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So typically, a typeless `button`, or an `input` with `type="button/submit"` will, by default, submit any and all ancestor `form`(s). If you are missing a closing `</form>`, the browser may be confused about when it ends. The way you have it written looks like it should work correctly, but...

One thing I have headaches with is using a single-form .NET setup on my CMS that will wrap the entire page in one big form. The CMS subsequently strips any `<form>` tags I may manually put in, and also, any `button/input` click will submit the page form. Maybe you have some CMS issues like that?

### Edit:

So looked at your code... the correct form seems to be submitting:

```
$('#physicians_form').on('submit',function(){ console.log('physicians'); });
$('#patients_form').on('submit',function(){ console.log('patients'); });
```

They log correctly. The correct form is submitting, but it seems your `validate.js` is only validating the first form no matter which form is submitted... I'm not familiar with the `validate.js` plugin, but is there perhaps a way you can designate which button should validate which form?

Comment: When I select "View page source" everything looks fine. No missing tags, the code is exactly as in my post with the PHP interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem, and there are two easy ways to fix it.

1. Place the button **inside the form**.  Most people do this, but if you do not, it may submit the first form on the page.  Make sure that your `<input type=` is submit, not button.
2. Using a button like this, `<input type="button" onclick="document.forms[1].submit()"/>` will submit the second form on the page.  Keep in mine that JS counts starting from 0.  Using `document.forms[0].submit()` would submit the first form.

Hope this helps!

Comment: What do you mean "Place the button INSIDE the form"? I can make it work with JavaScript, but I cannot understand why this don't work.

Comment: I see that you used the `<button>` HTML tag.  Try the same thing, but like this: `<input id="patients" style="margin-top:17px;" name="patients" type="submit"/>`.

Comment: Just tried. The same result. Something else is off here. :)